# I want to hide the navigation menu on a particular page

Tags: menus, navigation

I want to hide the navigation menu on a particular page. I know how to find the page id, but I am clueless about how to find the rest of the stuff, it would be great if someone could look into my blog's css from the link - idkwhereto.com

Thanks.

Comment: Does your theme use `body_class()` in header.php?

Comment: I just checked, yes it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action("wp_footer","Stack_308520_hide_menu");

function Stack_308520_hide_menu(){
    if(is_page(889 /*your page id*/){
    ?>
   <style> nav.width-navigation {display:none}</style>

   <?php
    }
}
```

this is a pure css solution

Comment: Why in footer? Why with PHP (and not with additional CSS in Customizer)?

Comment: It says "There are 22 errors which must be fixed before you can update this file." 

Markup is not allowed?

Answer (score 0):

If your theme uses `body_class`function in `header.php`, then you don't need to do anything in code...

Just add this code as Additional CSS in Customizer (Appearance -> Customize)

```
body.page-id-2 nav.width-navigation {display:none}
/* where 2 is the ID of your page */
```

But remember - it will only hide the navigation - it still will be in HTML code...